# Advice on having add-ons to app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that displays cartoon characters.  I wanted to start to offer additional characters, or even have accessories to place on the characters.

Can anyone offer advice as to the best way to do that?

Can that be done through the app store, or do I need to have my own mechanism for downloading them?

I have seen many apps where you can download clothes, etc. by touching an icon in the app, but I have not yet found any documentation or tutorials.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use In-App-Purchases for that. Apple will handle the financial side of things (charging the user through iTunes) and you'll have to handle the rest (downloading or unlocking the new content).

See the documentation: [Selling with In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)

And this tutorial: [Introduction to In-App Purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Thanks for the links, they were very helpful... one question, I understand how to verify receipt, but from what I read, it looks like I need to handle the downloading if the content myself... is that correct?  If so, any tips on downloading the content?

Comment: Yes, you have to handle the downloads yourself. Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with In-App-Purchases, so I can't give any tips about that. You could also just deliver your additional content with the game, but hide it. And then once the In-App-Purchase is verified, you unlock it.